# How do I protect my C# app from memory dump attack?

Tags: c#, security, memory-management

Dumping the memory allows an attacker to read the RAM of the entire OS, or more specifically of a single process. The attacker may save the dump and analyze it "offline" in order to search for sensitive data.

I am trying to understand how exactly this works and if there is a way to prevent it.

Now, let us suppose we have an app which uses AES to protect sensitive data. This is achieved by setting up the **key** in the aes.Key variable.

```
public static AesCryptoServiceProvider AESFunction()
    {
        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        try
        {
            aes.GenerateIV;
            aes.GenerateKey; //key is stored in aes.Key variable in the AesCryptoServiceProvider class
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            return aes;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

If we debug the aes object data structure in Visual Studio we can cleary see the array of bytes representing the key. If we dispose the object after using it, not anymore.

The question is: is the memory dump attack able to read this value despite disposing it after the usage?
If yes, is there an approach to prevent this from happening?

Comment: [SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: aes.Key is a sequence of bytes

Comment: @tym32167 SecureString should not be used. Ever. It isn't secure.

Comment: Same way you protect anything else code - wise that you don't want someone to see; don't give it to them

Comment: @MarcGravell can you elaborate a bit pls? I remember we  used it in past, so just want to know what Im missing.

Comment: @tym32167 the code to trivially decode it in a memory dump has been around since forever. It does not protect you from any interesting attack vector.

Comment: @tym32167 and since you can crawl a memory dump.by type: it really just highlights "here are the interesting bits to steal"

Comment: @MarcGravell gotcha, thx.

Comment: @tym32167 https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md

Answer (score 0):

On mainstream devices, the short answer is "no". If someone has admin or physical access to the box, they can grab the entire machine's memory - as a process dump, or an OS dump, and analyze it at their leisure. There is nothing you can do to prevent this except stop access from happening.

Comment: `It rather involved being on the other side of this airtight hatchway` as @RaymondChen would put it.

Comment: @asawyer great reference (here, for anyone else: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060508-22/?p=31283)